# Calculate double integral by changing the order of integration

Tags: integration

I'm trying to do my mathematical analysis homework but I have faced one struggle.

$$\iint_{\omega} y^2\,dx\,dy$$ where $\omega$ is bounded by the axis of abscissas and the first arch of the cycloid $$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x=a(t-\sin(t)) \\ 
y=a(1-\cos(t))
\end{array}
\right. 
$$ where $0≤t≤2\pi$ and $a>0$.

What I found out is the graph itself:[image]
And, let's say, I choose to integrate y from 0 to 2a and how can I express the function itself?

I need hints, how to create such an integral. Thank you!

Comment: Do you know Green's Formula ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem

Comment: @Kelenner No, I don't know it and the thing is that I can't use it. I need to create definite integral and found what the interval of this integral is.